# Multiple profiles per user?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, windows-7, user-profile, profile

Is it possible to have multiple profiles per user?

The reason why I ask is because I need to create test environments for hundreds of users, where the test environment has different software.  Unfortunately, the different software clashes with the existing software, which is why it needs to be on a different profile.

If it is possible to have multiple profiles per user, does anyone know how to set it up? If you do, please point me in the right direction.  If this is not the best solution, what will be a better solution to get around this problem?

Comment: Just as an offhand, this can actually be done in a very ridiculously easy but probably not desired way.  Windows 10 and windows 8.1/7 use different profile variables.  In a roaming environment, you can do things to a Windows 10 profile that won't transfer over to the Windows 8.1 profile of the same user.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you use roaming profiles, you could just set the "Profile Path" and "Home folder" parameters for a given user with a script. However, only one profile can be active at a time of course.

Comment: Script sounds ideal,  I've created a Logon script on exchange which has the required conditions.  Now I just need to know how to actually get the script to do the switch based on the conditions in the bat file.  How exactly do I do the profile switch from a bat file?

Comment: I would guess that the logon script is too late for this, as the AD values containing the home directory have already been read at this point. However I am not really a Windows expert, so I might be wrong.  My idea was more of a short powershell script that iterates over all affected users, make the change, run the test and then change it back afterwards.